# Should this question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, reopening

This is not a re-open request per-se, I just want to know what people think about [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125432/accepting-a-team-member-who-is-slated-to-quit-on-the-first-day).

While it is asking "about a specific choice" I still think this question can be answered objectively regarding the pros and cons to each method. I am currently on the fence about re-opening it, so I figured we could discuss it here.

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question had been reopened

Answer (score 1):

As I think it would vary by company and individual circumstances, I'd say it's far too broad and opinion based.

Should not be reopened.